# Getting data from grid and sending it to PHP in new window

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

There is an ExtJs store.
I want to send its data with POST method to PHP that will echo in a new window.
There is no problem getting the records and making string value readable by php.
I know I can simply send the data with GET method and window.open() function.
But is there a way to do it with POST?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot open a new window and send a POST to it. One workaround here would be to send an HTTP post back to the original page, and have that page return an ID of the record where the POST contents are stored; then, do a window.open(), passing that ID in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and Ajax (or maybe only ajax, but I wouldn't recommend that): 
http://jquery.com/ 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.post('target_url.php', { key : 'your data'});
    </script>
```

Comment: Try the code i added in my answer above. You only have to replace 'key' by a field name of your choice and 'your data' by the string you would like to submit.

Comment: Or you can use ExtJS of course (since it is already available - why haven't I noticed this? :D). http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/docs/#/api/Ext.Ajax

Comment: Thank you. But Are you sure it will open the php in a new window?

Comment: No, it will not. Another solution: You could create a (maybe invisible) html form with javascript and submit this form (with javascript of course).